# How do I get all of the circuit wires stuffed into the port for my new electrical panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I have a new electrical panel on the home I bought.  It has 28 slots in it.   I cannot fit more than 6 or 8 wires into each of the two the ports that feed to the house.  How do I get them all into the panel box?

Comment: If you look on the sides of the panel, you should see stamped circles.  They can be popped out to make openings for wires/cables.

Comment: If @crip659's comment isn't answer enough for you, please [edit] your question to include a picture of your panel for more complete details on how to do this. Also, do _not_ attempt to cram wires through the existing openings - that can lead to damage and overheating which leads to fire.

Comment: Seems odd for the cabinet to only have two ports.  Are you sure there aren't knockouts?

Comment: What make and model is this panel?

Comment: A picture would help. But most likely the two ports you are putting some cables in are already loaded past their design limit and you should be knocking out several more, each to hold (typically) 2 cables.

Comment: Panel is a recent GE.  I have photos and need to figure out how to add them to a post.